# MYSQL Like search with 2 Tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following problem. A video have multiple tags like high definition, 720p, 1080p and so on each tag has its own record. All tags are in own table its named tags.

Here are the sample table tag.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag` (
  `video_tag_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag_name` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `tag_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`video_tag_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

So when i use a like search from another table to this it shows me for each tag the same video.

How i could make this ?

Comment: Your `tag` is not a database, it's a table.

Answer (score 1):

We assume you mean *table* where you refer to *database*.

You will need to substitute your correct table structure for the videos table:

```
SELECT 
  videos.video_id,
  videos.name,
  tag.tag_name
FROM videos JOIN tag ON videos.video_id = tag.video_id
WHERE videos.name LIKE '%the name of your video%'
```

The above will list one row for each tag the video has.

To return a list of tags in one row, use `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT 
  videos.video_id,
  videos.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tag.tag_name) AS tags
FROM videos JOIN tag ON videos.video_id = tag.video_id
WHERE videos.name LIKE '%the name of your video%'
GROUP BY videos.video_id, videos.video_name
```

Comment: @SaschaHeim Try again. should be `tag` rather than `tags`